# Div with a border, stretch to fill height of div's inside

Tags: html, css, height

What I want to do is have this border go around the entire section of #main, which includes the menu and will include text. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to stretch to fit its contents. Here's the code

```css
    #logo{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0;
        z-index:1;
        width:850px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-425px;
    }

    #main{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-420px;
    width:840px;
    padding:5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#a8347b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 4px solid #a8347b;
     z-index:0;

    }
```

```html
    <div id="main">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="Logo.jpg"></div>

    <div id="centeredmenu">
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Photo Gallery</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Meet The Staff</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Our Facility</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Policies</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>FAQ's</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: There is a lot of CSS here and it's not entirely clear what is trying to be accomplished through it. Could you post a screenshot or mocked up image of what your end goal is (exactly what you would want this to look like in the end)? If I remove all your CSS and just add `#main{ padding:5px; border-radius:10px; border:4px solid #a8347b; }` I get an effect similar to what you describe you want. You could then add the CSS rules you want for other elements.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added two vertical div's going from top to bottom instead of the border.